# Copying straight text from latex generated file

Tags: pdf, latex, text-editing

I'm trying to do some corrections to a PDF documented generated from latex.

To do the corrections I first copy the text out of the PDF.

What happens is that in the generated PDF, the words are cut at the right when they don't fit the margin, for example, when the word "paragraph" is too big to fit, it will be cut like:

```
word1 word2\n 
word3 para-\n
graph word4\n
```

Also the linebreaks are not made when necessary, but are always at the end of the text.

I don't have access to the original. So this is a problem when I copy the text to edit somewhere, as I end up with a bunch of unnecessary linebreaks and wordbreaks (not sure how these last are really called).

Is there a way to copy the text correctly from the pdf file?

Is this something that the PDF file does for the words to fit the page neatly, without text justification?

Comment: So what's your question exactly? It might also be better suited for the LaTeX stack exchange. If so flag it for migration.

Comment: i'm gona leave it here for a while, as this may be pdf related too, i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

These two regexes ran in that order should work.

```
s/-\n//g
s/([^.])\n/$1 /g
```